# How to Add contributors to published sitecore marketplace module

Tags: sitecore

I had published module in sitecore marketplace module 
but I can't add contributors or Edit some Text 
Note that I used the page Editor Mode 
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or related. You should ask this question in the Sitecore Community Forums instead.

Comment: thank you I added the question to http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I _still_ think it is a better question for the Forums rather than the StackExchange network.